# Share the Github Repo with someone wothout making it public

Tags: github

I want to share my GitHub repository or project with a recruiter, but I can't make my repo public, how can I do it. Like share using a link or something.

Comment: Is this on a repository owned by an organization or an individual account?

Comment: What did you try? Where did that fail? Please describe the effort you put into solving your problem when asking a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Okay i found that i can add people to see my repository, but i am asking like can i make a unique link of my repository and then share it with someone, so that only person having that link can see my repo, not others, can it do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can give direct access to the user in a private repo.

1. Goto settings of the repo.
2. Select the Collaborators tab, Then select Add People.[Git Add People](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRADA.png)

Comment: yeah i know that, iam asking that that i can add people to see my repository, but i am asking like can i make a unique link of my repository and then share it with someone, so that only person having that link can see my repo, not others, can it do that?